# How to disable a nested heading html element using jsf rendered attribute

Tags: html, jsf

I have a JSF page that contains:

```
<div class="tableCaption">
  <h2>Batch Details</h2>
</div>
```

and a CSS that defines the look of .tableCaption h2

I want to wrap the above div in a JSF component that has the 'rendered' attribute so I can enable/disable the div but I cannot find the appropriate component. Is it even possible to wrap arbitrary HTML components and switch them on/off?

If that's not possible is there a way to use
     
somehow to make it use the CSS already defined for .tableCaption h2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`<h:panelGroup layout="block">`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/panelGroup.html) to get a HTML `<div>` element.

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="tableCaption" rendered="#{condition}">
    <h2>Batch Details</h2>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Alternatively, when using JSP as view technology, you can use [`<f:verbatim>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/verbatim.html) instead if the sole body is pure HTML.

```
<f:verbatim rendered="#{condition}">
    <div class="tableCaption">
        <h2>Batch Details</h2>
    </div>
</f:verbatim>
```

*Please note that this tag is been deprecated in JSF 2.0 in favour of Facelets.*

Or, when you're using Facelets as view technology, the [`<ui:fragment>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/fragment.html) should do:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{condition}">
    <div class="tableCaption">
        <h2>Batch Details</h2>
    </div>
</ui:fragment>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately I forgot to mention I was on JSF 1.1 and none of the above will work as they are JSF1.2 or onwards. I have ended up using the MyFaces Tomahawk library for JSF1.1 - specifically the `<t:div>` tag.

Comment: The `<f:verbatim>` is supported in JSF 1.1.

Comment: The `<f:verbatim>` does not support `rendered` attribute in JSF1.1

Comment: @user1169330: you're right. Just use `<h:panelGroup>` instead then. Or just upgrade JSF, JSF 1.1 is dead technology.